# MVC EF6 insert with multiple foreign keys

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

Hi I need an idea how to insert parent/child rows in EF6 with 2 foreign keys if rows does not exist before. I'm working in c# MVC 5 with MSSQL db using EF6 for db communication.
I have 4 tables with corresponding classes.
[image]

Description is next: table have columns and rows. Row has cells but since one cell belongs to column also column has cells too. That means that one cell is determent by row and column (using foreign keys).
Model classes for that are:

```
[Table("TD_Tables")]
public class TD_Table
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int TD_TableId { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public string Orientation { get; set; }
    public int TenderDefinitionId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("TenderDefinitionId")]
    public TenderDefinition TenderDefinition { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TD_Column> Columns { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TD_Row> Rows { get; set; }       
}

[Table("TD_Rows")]
public class TD_Row
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int TD_RowId { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public int Sort { get; set; }

    public int TD_TableId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("TD_TableId")]
    public TD_Table Table { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TD_Cell> Cells { get; set; }        
}

[Table("TD_Columns")]
public class TD_Column
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int? TD_ColumnId { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public string ColumnName { get; set; }
    public int Sort { get; set; }

    public int TD_TableId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("TD_TableId")]
    public TD_Table Table { get; set; }

    public int TD_ColumnTypeId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("TD_ColumnTypeId")]
    public TD_ColumnType ColumnType { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TD_Cell> Cells { get; set; }
}

[Table("TD_Cells")]
public class TD_Cell
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int TD_CellId { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public string CellValue { get; set; }

    public int? TD_ColumnId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("TD_ColumnId")]     
    public virtual TD_Column Column { get; set; }

    public int? TD_RowId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("TD_RowId")]
    public virtual TD_Row Row { get; set; } 
}
```

For insert into DB I'm creating a table model object with all rows, columns 
and cells first and insert all in one call. Creating a table model object:

```
{
var model = new TD_Table();
model.Active = true;
//number of columns to create
for(int i =0; i < columnsNum.AsInt(0); i++)
{
    var column = new TD_Column()
    {
        Active = true,
        ColumnName = "", 
        ColumnTypeId = (int)Core.Enums.TD_ColumnType.Text,
        Sort = model.Columns.Count
    };
    model.Columns.Add(column);
}
//number of rows to create
for (int i = 0; i < rowsNum.AsInt(0); i++)
{
    var row = new TD_Row()
    {
        Active = true,
        Sort = i,
        TD_TableId = model.TD_TableId
    };
    for(int c = 0; c < model.Columns.Count; c++)
    {
        var cell = new TD_Cell()
        {
            Active = true,
            CellValue = "",
            TD_ColumnId = model.Columns[c].TD_ColumnId,
            Column = model.Columns[c]               
        };
        model.Columns[c].Cells.Add(cell);
        row.Cells.Add(cell);
    }
    model.Rows.Add(row);
}
// add table model in parent definition model
tender.TenderContent.TenderDefinition.Tables.Add(model);
}
```

In repository I'm updating existing parent definition and adding a new table or updating existing one with all child rows:

```
Tender Update(Tender tender)
    {
        using (var db = new TenderDbContext())
        {
            var t = db.Tenders.
                    Include(x => x.TenderContent).
                    Include(x => x.TenderContent.TenderDefinition).                        
                    //Include(x => x.TenderContent.TenderDefinition.Tables).
                    Include(x => x.TenderContent.TenderDefinition.Tables.Select(y => y.Columns.Select(z => z.Cells))).
                    Include(x => x.TenderContent.TenderDefinition.Tables.Select(y => y.Rows.Select(z => z.Cells))).
                    Include(x => x.TenderContent.Survey).
                    Include(x => x.TenderContent.Survey.Questions).
                    Where(x => x.TenderId == tender.TenderId).FirstOrDefault();

            foreach (var table in tender.TenderContent.TenderDefinition.Tables.Where(x => x.Active))
            {
                var tableId = table.TD_TableId;
                var existingTable = t.TenderContent.TenderDefinition.Tables
                    .Where(c => c.TD_TableId == tableId)
                    .FirstOrDefault();

                if (existingTable != null)
                {
                    db.Entry(existingTable).CurrentValues.SetValues(table);
                    if (table.Columns != null && table.Columns.Any())
                    {
                        foreach (var column in table.Columns.Where(x => x.Active))
                        {
                            var existingColumn = db.TD_Columns.Where(x => x.TD_ColumnId == column.TD_ColumnId).FirstOrDefault();
                            if (existingColumn != null)
                                db.Entry(existingColumn).CurrentValues.SetValues(column);
                            else
                                existingTable.Columns.Add(column);
                        }
                    }
                    if (table.Rows != null && table.Rows.Any())
                    {
                        foreach (var row in table.Rows.Where(x => x.Active))
                        {
                            var existingRow = db.TD_Rows.Where(x => x.TD_RowId == row.TD_RowId).FirstOrDefault();
                            if (existingRow != null)
                            {
                                db.Entry(existingRow).CurrentValues.SetValues(row);
                                foreach (var cell in row.Cells.Where(x => x.Active))
                                {
                                    var cellExisting = db.TD_Cells.Where(q => q.TD_CellId == cell.TD_CellId).FirstOrDefault();
                                    if (cellExisting != null)
                                        db.Entry(cellExisting).CurrentValues.SetValues(cell);
                                    else
                                        row.Cells.Add(cell);
                                }
                            }
                            else
                                existingTable.Rows.Add(row);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                    t.TenderContent.TenderDefinition.Tables.Add(table); //insert table with all children
            }                
            db.SaveChanges();
            return t;
        }
    }
```

My main problem is that after inserting a new table eg. t.TenderContent.TenderDefinition.Tables.Add(table) TD_Cells rows are duplicated with RowId value populated and ColumnId is null and ColumnId value poplated and RowId is null. So if I want to insert 10 cells with 2 foreign keys row and column id I have 20 cells with 1 key only
Problem is that when I created a cell I added that cell in column and in row and EF does not know how to map that cell to have 2 foreign keys. If I added only in one will have only 1 key populated. Can anybody find what is wrong here and what is the best way to handle situation like this?

Comment: Maybe tables TD_Rows and TD_Columns has many to many relationship and TD_Cell is just middle table which contains both foreign keys. That means I should add that relation in db context and populate data in diff way

Comment: I tried with many to many sugested solutions and no luck. EF cannot map relations between cell, row and column since I need to create relations from different side, from table eg. Create first table then add row, add cell and finally add cell. All many to many solutions sugested to create first cell and then all others. What is the best solutions for this problem?